# Validation Group on "NotBlank" constraint makes field have "required" attribute when not used

Tags: html, symfony, validation, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have an entity field as follows:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"myGroup"})
 */
protected $field;
```

Then I call an entity form without any validation groups (my `configureOptions` function only sets `data_class`). But the field is being created with the `required="required"` attribute in the HTML:

```
<input id="entity_field" name="entity[field]" required="required" type="text">
```

But if I fiddle with the HTML and take out the `required="required"`, the validation works as intended in the backend (i.e., `NotBlank` doesn't apply for this form).

Answer (score 1):

The annotation `@Assert\NotBlank(groups={"myGroup"})` is server side related, the input attribute `required="required"` is defined in the construction of your form.
If this field is not required you should defined required option to false in your form, take a look at the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#field-type-options)

> The required Option
>
> The most common option is the required option, which can be applied to any field. By default, the required option is set to true, meaning that HTML5-ready browsers will apply client-side validation if the field is left blank. If you don't want this behavior, either disable HTML5 validation or set the required option on your field to false:
>
> Also note that setting the required option to true will not result in server-side validation to be applied. In other words, if a user submits a blank value for the field (either with an old browser or web service, for example), it will be accepted as a valid value unless you use Symfony's NotBlank or NotNull validation constraint.
>
> In other words, the required option is "nice", but true server-side validation should always be used.

Comment: But if I take the `@Assert\NotBlank` out, the `required` attribute disappears. In other words, something in the framework reads the `NotBlank` and slaps a `required="required"` in the form. Shouldn't it be smart and only read the `NotBlank` when I'm in the right validation group? Is it a bug?

Comment: @Heitor : At my knowledge there is no relation between server side validation and client side validation in symfony

Comment: The server-side and client-side might validate separatedly, but when you set certain "@Assert" constraints they work in both. Try setting a `NotBlank` in a field, you will get automatic `required="required"` in your HTML. Try setting a `Length` constraint, you will get `maxlength="X"`.

Of course, I'm assuming Symfony Standard Edition default behavior.